# EF Query with OrderBy fails

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

I'm sure there is a simple answer to this, but I can't seem to nail it down.

I have the following code,

```
internal override async Task FetchDataModel()
{
    var dateCutoff = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-PeriodInDays);

     var query = this.DB.Jobs
         .IsDelivered()
         .Where(x => x.DeliveredTime.Value.Date >= dateCutoff)
         .GroupBy(x => new { x.Pet.OwnerId, x.Pet.Owner.First, x.Pet.Owner.Last })
         .Select(x => new MVPCustomerDTO
         {
             OwnerId = x.Key.OwnerId,
             OwnerName = $"{x.Key.First} {x.Key.Last}",
             JobCount = x.Count(),
             TotalSpend = x.Sum(a => (a.Price ?? 0M) - a.Discount) 
                      + this.DB.JobExtras
                               .Where(a => a.Job.Pet.OwnerId == x.Key.OwnerId)
                               .Where(a => a.Job.DeliveredTime.Value.Date >= dateCutoff)
                               .Sum(a => a.Price),
         })
/*==>Problem Line*/ .OrderByDescending(x => x.TotalSpend)
         .Take(25);

          var result = await query
                      .ToListAsync()
                      .ConfigureAwait(false);

          this.Model = result;
}
```

I cannot figure out how to get around this exception.  Its EF core 3.0 code. The OrderByDescending is causing the issue.  If I remove it, the query works.  I thought maybe it had to do with the TotalSpend, so trying to wrap my head around this, I removed the TotalSpend field, and changed the OrderByDescending to orderby JobCount, and got the same results.  I'm sure this is related to server side translation, but I can't seem to get my head wrapped around this to get around the issue.

Help me see the light please!?!

The exception being throw is:

```
 System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'key')
    at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.FindEntry(TKey key)
    at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.SqlExpressions.SelectExpression.GetMappedProjection(ProjectionMember projectionMember)
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalSqlTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitExtension(Expression extensionExpression)
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalSqlTranslatingExpressionVisitor.Translate(Expression expression)
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.TranslateExpression(Expression expression)
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.TranslateLambdaExpression(ShapedQueryExpression shapedQueryExpression, LambdaExpression lambdaExpression)
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.TranslateOrderBy(ShapedQueryExpression source, LambdaExpression keySelector, Boolean ascending)
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
    at System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
    at System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryCompilationContext.CreateQueryExecutor[TResult](Expression query)
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Database.CompileQuery[TResult](Expression query, Boolean async)
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.CompileQueryCore[TResult](IDatabase database, Expression query, IModel model, Boolean async)
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass12_0`1.<ExecuteAsync>b__0()
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQueryCore[TFunc](Object cacheKey, Func`1 compiler)
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQuery[TResult](Object cacheKey, Func`1 compiler)
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.ExecuteAsync[TResult](Expression query, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.ExecuteAsync[TResult](Expression expression, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1.GetAsyncEnumerator(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredCancelableAsyncEnumerable`1.GetAsyncEnumerator()
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    at GroomShop.Web.ReportGenerators.MVPCustomerReport.FetchDataModel() in C:\Workspace\GroomShop\GroomShop.Web\ReportGenerators\MVPCustomerReport.cs:line 203
```

Comment: Just curious... do you have a working SQL version of your query? And if so, can you share it?  I often find when creating complex queries in LINQ that if I have a working SQL query to build from, it goes much easier.

Comment: Please add Include for Pet.Owner. I am guessing, x.Key.First might be null.

Comment: Ivan had the answer.. It was the string interpolation.  Strangely, the query worked if you removed the OrderBy clause suggesting to me that the projection is happening after the database in the library, and introducing the orderby trys to project in the DB and  then order that projection... Thanks for your thoughts!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The exception is misleading. The problem is the interpolated string inside the projection (`Select`) which of course cannot be translated to SQL and should generate client evaluation exception telling you that. Instead (most likely EF Core implementation bug) you get the aforementioned misleading exception.

The solution is of course to avoid non translatable constructs/methods like interpolated strings, `Format` / `ToString` methods with format strings / culture info arguments. Instead, use string concatenation (and parameterless `ToString` methods if needed), e.g. replace

```
OwnerName = $"{x.Key.First} {x.Key.Last}",
```

with

```
OwnerName = x.Key.First + " " + x.Key.Last,
```

Comment: Wow!  That ended up being the solution.  What I find interesting is that the query works with the string interpolation if you leave the OrderByDescending clause off.  Is that because  the projection is happening after the database and before the return, whereas when you put the orderby clause in, its trying to do the projection in the database and then use a database orderby ?

Comment: Correct. 3.0 supports client evaluation only for "*top-level projection (essentially, the last call to `Select()`)*" - see [Restricted client evaluation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/#restricted-client-evaluation).

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your query fails will probably be that `Jobs.Pet` or `Jobs.Pet.Owner` is being null within certain database entries.

When you then access `x.Key.OwnerId` or `x.Key.First` or `x.Key.Last` inside your LINQ `Select()` it will throw an exception

Answer (score 0):

When the query uses OrderByDescending(), the query is looking at more rows than simply taking the Top(25). OrderBy has to hit all the rows in question in order to order them. One possibility is that you were getting lucky that the Top(25) rows didn't hit any nulls.

If this is the case, then nulls will either have to be handled or excluded from the query, depending on the requirements. Otherwise, something else is going on.

Comment: Good thought!  Unfortunately that doesn't seem to be the cause.  Because this is a development environment, the data is limited, and there are only 4 rows in the result set so the Take(25) in this case is extraneous.  Also, when I run the query without the OrderBy clause, the query runs with no problems, and there are no NULL fields in the result.  I get the correct answer, just not ordered.